# Having trouble getting MAUI Data Bindings to work with material components card

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I'm having trouble getting MAUI data bindings to play nicely with the Material Components Card (in code `mdc:Card`).

If I remove the `mdc:Card` the bindings work perfectly fine, which makes me believe the issue lies specifically with that component and needing to update the binding context in some way.

The `TapGestureRecogniser` is not working, neither are the actual data bindings further down.

Visual Studio at least seems to recognise the bindings because it autocompletes when setting the binding context paths.

**Example Class**:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML Code**:
I've tried to remove as much of the extra styling fluff as possible hence the ellipses

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfFooBars}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout .... />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:FooBar">
            <mdc:Card ...>
                <mdc:Card.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:ThisPageViewModel}}, Path=ItemSelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                </mdc:Card.GestureRecognizers>
                <StackLayout ...>
                    <!--There was another component here dont worry about the double up on the stack layout-->
                    <StackLayout ...>
                        <Grid ...>
                            <Label ... Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue=Name}" />
                            <Label ... Text="{Binding Description, FallbackValue=Description}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </mdc:Card>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

I attempted set the `x:DataType` of the `mdc:Card` to `x:DataType="models:FooBar"` as well as the `BindingContext` (with something similar to the tap gesture), but that didn't work.

Googling the issue returns some similar but unrelated problems - the x:DataType of the ContentPage is set to the `viewmodel`, not the `collectionview` model.

Comment: It might be caused by a known issue: https://github.com/mdc-maui/mdc-maui/issues/56